Storing global data in a .NET Console App
I'm making a .net console app that is an arena discord bot, and on bot startup, there will be a lot of Character data loaded from a JSON file (I'm porting a Unity app and this correlates to all the ScriptableObject data). For now, I'd like to just keep this character data in memory until eventually moving it to a DB. I'm wondering what best practice is when storing this type of global data in a console app. In looking at example code, I see examples of a public class with static variables storing the data and static methods retrieving it. Here's an example of what I'm planning to do. Is this a typical approach?
    public sealed class CharacterData
    {
        private static List<Character> characters = new();

        public static void AddCharacterData(Character character)
        {
            characters.Add(character);            
        }
        public static Character GetCharacterData(Guid guid)
        {
            return characters.Find(x => x.id == guid);            
        }
    }

    public class Character
    {
        public Guid id = Guid.NewGuid();
        public string myName = "";
        public int level = 1;
    }

It's working like this, I'm just looking for best practice advice.

use a .env file.  This way, you can update the values in the file without having to recompile the application.

Nothing terrible about this :) Carry on.

For a small project, this is probably fine. You're just "memoizing" the data using a static field.
If this is likely to grow, there are various issues to consider:

If the collection is being accessed and modified from different threads simultaneously, you could have thread-safety problems. Make sure the whole collection is created synchronously before things start using it, or find a way to make your solution thread-safe.
If you end up with a large number of characters, Find will be slow. Consider using a Dictionary-like structure so lookup times don't depend on how many characters there are.
Using static/global variables is generally considered bad practice because it tightly couples classes to specific implementations and instances. It may be better to have a class that keeps track of the characters in an instance field, and set up dependency injection to inject the same instance of that class everywhere that it's needed. This makes the instance effectively global in practice, while allowing you to create or mock instances to create isolated unit tests.
Pay attention to which aspects of a Character you expect can change. By making id a public field, you make it possible for code to change the ID. If you have stored the character data in a way that's indexed by ID (like a Dictionary), the collection could get out of sync with the IDs of the items inside. Using properties will allow you to be explicit about which values other classes are allowed to change. Using constructors and readonly fields or get-only properties can prevent certain values from changing after the object is constructed.

